Trouble understanding the proof of the Second $\Sigma_3$ Representation Theorem
The Second $\Sigma_3$ representation theorem states that if $A$ is $\Sigma_3$ then there is a computable function $h(x,y)$ such that when $x \in A$ there is a unique $W_{h(x,y)}$ which is infinite (in which case it is $\omega$) and when $x \not \in A$ then each $W_{h(x,y)}$ is finite.
I am having a lot of trouble understanding the proof of this result. It is Theorem 4.3.11 in Soare's book Turing Computability, Theory and Applicatons, page 90.
Here is what I do understand: Let $g$ be a similar computable function, but all we know is that when $x \in A$ then $W_{g(x,y)}$ is exactly infinite (and = $\omega$) all but finitely often. (The existence of such a function is guaranteed by the previous theorem.)
Define
$$f(x,m,s) = m + \Sigma_{n < y} |W_{g(x,n),s}|$$
and let $y$ be the least such that $W_{g(x,y)}$ is infinite. Then $lim_s f(x,u,s)$ is finite when $u \leq y$ and infinite when $u > y$.
That's pretty much it. I can't make heads or tails out of the rest of the proof.
Here is the construction he gives. We watch the $W_{g(x,y)}$'s get enumerated.
Stage s+1: Let $z = f(x,y,s)$. Enumerate into $W_{h(x,z)}$ everything enumerated into $W_{g(x,y)}$ by stage $s$.
QUESTION: In the verification, he claims if $x \in A$ then $W_{h(x,u)}$ finite for all $u > lim_s f(x,y,s)$? Why is this? (The "idea" is that instead of enumerating $W_{g(x,y)}$ into a single set, we "scatter it" across infinitely many sets, each of which ends up finite. But this is NOT a formal proof, and I don't have any guarantee that other things aren't accidentally getting enumerated into those sets that are supposed to be finite. For example, f is clearly not one-to-one or anything.)
Further questions: He doesn't mention it but it must also be checked that $W_{h(x,u)}$ is finite for all $u < lim_s f(x,y,s)$, and I am having trouble with this argument as well (see below). I also  do not understand his verification for $x \not \in A$.
More I understand: If $m \leq y$ then there is a stage $s_0$ after which $f(x,m,s)$ no longer increases. After that stage, we then continually dump $W_{g(x,y)}$ into $W_{h(x,z)}$ where $z = lim_s f(x,m,s)$, so $W_{g(x,y)} \subseteq   W_{h(x,z)}$. (It seems Soare assumes nothing else enumerates into this set but I don't know how to guarantee this.) If nothing else gets dumped, this is finite when $m < y$ and exactly $\omega$ when $m = y$.
Now note for $m \leq y$, $lim_s f(x,m,s) = m+ \Sigma_{n < y} |W_{g(x,n)}|$ so $lim_s f(x,m,s) \leq lim_s f(x,y,s)$.
However, there is a gap. I do not understand why this alone means $W_{h(x,n)}$ is finite for all $n < lim_s f(x,y,s)$; I just know that it (probably) is for some.

Note that $W_{g(x,y)}$ tells us about whether or not $x\in A$ from the previous theorem as it's stated at the beginning of the proof. As such we can see why the case 2 holds for if we fix $x\notin A$ we know $W_{g(x,y)}$ is finite for any y from the previous theorem, which means for any y we will have that $W_{h(x,z)}$ shares a finite amount of elements with a finite amount of sets, where z will be well defined. Similarily for case 1, because of how $W_{g(x,y)}$ is defined, if $x\in A$ we know such an y exists.

I will try to spell out the missing details. Take an $x\in A$, then we have that $\forall^\infty y\;W_{g(x,y) }=\omega$ and $\forall y\; W_{g(x,y)}=\omega$ or is finite. Let $u_x=\min\{y:W_{g(x,y)}=\omega\}$. We have that for all $y<u_x\; W_{g(x,y)}$ is finite, so $\lim_s f(x,u_x,s)$ exists and we will denote it by $z$.
Consider the case where $v>z$. We have that a number $w$ can be enumerated in $W_{h(x,v)}$ at step $s$ only if there is a $y<v$ and $s$ such that $f(x,y,s)=v$ . As you observed, if $y\leq u_x$ then $\lim_s f(x,y,s)\leq y+\sum_{r<y} |W_{g(x,r)}|<\infty$ so in particular for all $s$ we have that $f(x,y,s)\neq v$. For all $y>u_x$ we have that $f(x,y,s)$ diverges with respect to $s$. In particular, we have that every $y$ such that $u_x<y\leq v$ there exists finitely many $s$ such that $f(x,y,s)=v$. So in particular the set $\{(y,s):u_x<y\leq v\wedge f(x,y,s)=v\}$ is finite, and so the elements enumerated in $W_{h(x,v)}$ must also be finite.
Consider the case where $v<z$. As in the previous point, we have that a number is enumerated in $W_{h(x,v)}$ if there exists $s$ and $y<v$ such that $f(x,y,s)=v$ and $w\in W_{g(x,y)}[s]$. If $y$ is such that $u_x\leq y\leq v$ then we have there will only be finitely many $s$ such that $f(x,y,s)=v$ and so they will only enumerated finitely elements in $W_{h(x,v)}$. For $y<u_x$, we have that $W_{g(x,y)}$ is finite, and so only finitely many numbers can be enumerated in $W_{h(x,v)}$ by $y<u_x$.
For the case where $x\notin A$, you have that for all $y$ the set $W_{g(x,y)}$ is finite. So in particular, you have that $W_{h(x,v)}\subseteq \bigcup_{y\leq v}W_{(g(x,y)}$. This means that $W_{h(x,v)}$ will also be finite.

Yes, ensuring only finitely much "junk" gets enumerated into $W_{h(x,y)}$ is crucial for all parts of the verification and this does it.
It seems like Soare could have defined $f(x,m,s) = <x, m, \Sigma_{n<y} |W_{g(x,n),s}| >$ which would have guaranteed this in an obvious way and significantly simplified the proof.
